# Multipart e-mail; Plain text made as an attachment

Tags: email, email-attachments, multipart

I'm attempting to send a multipart e-mail message including a normal plain text part as well as attachments.

However the problem I have is that on some e-mail clients such as gmail the plain text part is not shown but made as a attachment called noname.txt. On other clients such as thunderbird it appears to be shown correctly. All the attachments seem to work correctly, only the text is also made as an attachment for some reason. Everything below is as sent although I removed some of the stuff. All the CRLF's are correct etc.

I have attempted to make another CRLF before the boundary to the first attachment but that didn't appear to help.

Please note that using a framework for sending the e-mail is not an option and I need to construct it manually.

I can't seem to figure out the problem, so any help is much appreciated. Thanks

```
To: "Name" <email@name.com>
From: "Name" <email@name.com>
Subject: Subject
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=-----0d2e2a0ba179f065ae392b2527b2eb39-----;
Date: Fri, 16 Aug 2013 20:46:14 +0200
MIME-Version: 1.0

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
-------0d2e2a0ba179f065ae392b2527b2eb39-----
Content-Type: text/plain charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Text goes here
-------0d2e2a0ba179f065ae392b2527b2eb39-----
Content-Type: application/x-msexcel
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file1.xls"

BASE64 encoded file

-------0d2e2a0ba179f065ae392b2527b2eb39-----
Content-Type: application/x-msexcel
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file2.xls"

BASE64 encoded file

-------0d2e2a0ba179f065ae392b2527b2eb39-----
Content-Type: application/x-msexcel
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file3.xls"

BASE64 encoded file

-------0d2e2a0ba179f065ae392b2527b2eb39-------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the issue. It was a missing semicolon here:

```
Content-Type: text/plain charset="UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the header `Content-Disposition: inline` for your `text/plain` data. More info [in RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1806.txt)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time. It didn't help though. See my answer.